# The characteristic and the usage of a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

For example, I have two classes; a.java and b.java.  a.java is an empty class and extends java.util.ArrayList.

When I create an object from a.java in b.java, do I have the same object like the sample arraylist object below? If not, what are the differences?

```
ArrayList<String> sample= new ArrayList<String>();
```

I try to figure out the logic of inheritance and its various usages. 
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: It's practically impossible to tell what you're asking here.

Comment: @SBI please, see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are extending one class (in this case `ArrayList`), the first thing that you must do in the constructor of the subclass is to call the constructor of the base class like this :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo<T> extends ArrayList<T> {
    public Foo() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Because the base class is `ArrayList`, doing this :

```
Foo<String> dummy = new Foo<String>();
```

is equivalent to :

```
ArrayList<String> sample= new ArrayList<String>();
```

All functions that you have on the ArrayList can be call with the variable `dummy`.

Using inheritance can be useful in many use-cases :

1. Adding new functionalities to an existing object without changing it
2. A way to have polymorphism
3. So on ...